# Color of an object as a Variable in Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, data-visualisation

Is it possible to have the color of an object as a Variable?
In my particular case I want to change the color of a rectangle with my datasets.

Comment: @Ovaryraptor thanks for answering. Where do you put that switching statement? is it some kind of scripting? thanks

Comment: I didn't read your question correctly. https://helpx.adobe.com/illustrator/using/data-driven-graphics-templates-variables.html might help you in the right direction.

Answer (score 3):

Please see my LinkedIn article here: https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/illustrator-variable-data-advanced-techniques-recoloring-vasily-hall/

It describes the usage of a menu-item script in the batch action which processes each dataset with a custom routine which colorizes shapes. The script called "Recolor.jsx" takes variable data from text frames associated with a variable field and uses it as a parameter for its function in setting document object colors. You can make creative uses of all the various application methods and their parameters.